# Module object has no attribute 'urlopen' error in python VISUAL STUDIO AS IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

may someone please help me what is wrong with my python code below.
while running the below code i am getting error as "

```
Error:
Module object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Code:

```
import urllib
u=urllib.urlopen('http://bata.in/bataindia/c-5553_cl-2/men/boots.html')
data = u.read()
f=open('rt22.xml','wb')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Python 3.4 and used VS2014

Thanks a lot

Comment: In Python 3.x, `urlopen` is located in the `request` sub module. In short, use `from urllib.request import urlopen`.

Comment: @Jim: Thanks Jim, but when i tried to import like this, from urllib.request import urllib....its throwing import type error. like cannot import urllib. please suggest

Comment: It is `from urllib.request import urlopen` not `from urllib.request import urllib`.

Comment: @Jim: so sorryyyyyyyyy

Comment: @Jim: name 'urllib' is not defined : Name error occur

Comment: Well, you imported `urlopen` so `urllib` is not in your namespace now. You need to change your line `u=urllib.urlopen('http://bata.in/bataindia/c-5553_cl-2/men/boots.html')` to `u=urlopen('http://bata.in/bataindia/c-5553_cl-2/men/boots.html')`

Comment: @Jim: Thanks a lot Jim.  :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you're just starting out, take a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) on the main python site. It covers a great deal of what the language offers.